# Pure JavaScript code for HTTP Basic Authentication?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, basic-authentication

Where can I find reference code that implements a HTTP Basic Authentication client in pure JavaScript, suitable for AJAX?

Extra points for code, or pointers to code, that can be used independent of JS toolkits like YUI. No points for Java, Flash/Flex, PHP frameworks, etc.

Comment: What do you mean pure javascript? You're looking for a way to set cookies with javascript without the page reloading?

Comment: Basic Authentication does not use cookies but HTTP headers.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The five-parameter version of the `XMLHttpRequest.open` method allows you to specify the username and password. ([WHATWG spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method))

```
xhr.open(method, url, async, username, password)
```

Answer (score 24):

There is a good article/tutorial written by [Paul James](http://www.peej.co.uk/). I used it some time ago and it worked for me.

[HTTP Authentication with HTML Forms](http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/http-auth-with-html-forms.html)

> [...] XMLHTTPRequest, it can submit the
>   correct HTTP auth headers for us.
>   Rather than adjusting the URL the form
>   submits to, we can use XMLHTTPRequest
>   to do a request before the form
>   submits supplying the entered username
>   and password.
>
> This will set up the
>   browser with the HTTP auth credentials
>   so it'll also send them with our
>   actual form submission login request.

Comment: More than what I was looking for, but looks like a very nice way to replace the browser's default login dialog.

Comment: I tried this and it works but I get this in Chrome console:
Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are deprecated, and will be blocked in M59, around June 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

Are there any other methods?