# Control HTTP basic authentication using javascript

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication

I'd like to check if a URL is protected by a Http Basic Authentication using javascript.
Here is what I have so far :

```
  function showFailure(){ alert("FAILED ") }
  function showSuccess(){ alert("SUCCESS") }

  var myRequest = new Request({
    url: 'http://localhost/access_protected_HTTP_BASIC', 
    method: 'get', 
    onSuccess: showSuccess,
    onFailure: showFailure
  }).send();
```

But that actually opens the browser login popup to access the resource.
Is there a way not to trigger that popup?

Thanks!

Note : I use mootools in this example but I'd take any javascript example that does the trick :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491914/pure-javascript-code-for-http-basic-authentication), you can manually pass a username and password when sending a request. (And according to the [MooTools Docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request), the `user` and `password` parameters do exactly this.)

Further, the [`XMLHttpRequest` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method) says:

> If authentication fails, Authorization is not in the list of author request headers, request username is non-null, and request password is non-null, user agents **must not** prompt the end user for their username and password.

This means you can set a dummy username and password, and the browser won't prompt the user. If you get back a 401 status code, it means authorization is required.

Answer (score 0):

all you should need to do is add a header `Authorization: Basic *Base64EncodedString*` where `*Base64EncodedString*` is `base64Encode(username+':'+password)` it should be easy enough to find a base64encode function out there. YMMV