# How to send login credentials to popup window

Tags: html, forms, post, authentication, get

When logging-in automatically, the username and password are usually sent to the form via **POST** or **GET** functions. However, I'm trying to automate the login for a third-party site *(namely an IP camera resource)* which pops-up the login forms like these:

***in Chrome:***

[image]

***in FireFox:***

[image]

***in IE 11:***

[image]

The dev tools of Chrome, Firefox and IE don't seem to be able to inspect the popup. How would we obtain the form's input names, and how could we send it to the form.

Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the protocol and particular implementation you may be able to use http://username:password@domain.com

Comment: But that approach doesn't work in IE. How could we login in via **POST** or **GET**?

Comment: It should work in IE if it works in the other browsers (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032734/automatic-authentication-using-javascript ) you won't be able to use GET or POST because the authentication type (HTTP) doesn't read the values from GET or POST

Comment: Thanks again Tom. Unfortunately, it seems that IE has disabled that feature by default, and the only workaround would be for the user to change some registry settings: [_Microsoft Support_](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834489).