# Native browser login prompt

Tags: php, jquery

Is there a way to trigger the native browser login prompt UI (using PHP or jQuery) but to use the values that the user enters into the prompt **before** the browser tries to authenticate using its own methods?

[image]

The only things I have found in relation to this are some answers concerning [ASP](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/) and [Java](http://captaindanko.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/how-does-browsers-native-login-prompt.html).

Failing this, is there a 'standard' jQuery UI I can use? Similar to the 'standard' datetime jQuery UI for example?

Comment: please explain what the native browser login ui is?

Comment: windows chrome (or firefox?) prompt attached

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491914/pure-javascript-code-for-http-basic-authentication

Comment: What does "before the browser tries to authenticate using its own methods" mean? Just send the authentication headers to show the prompt and handle the values using `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`.

Comment: @PeeHaa - I guess that's what I'm asking; what are the 'authentication headers' I need to send (to where) to display the prompt?

Comment: I would say the manual is a good resource http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php.

Comment: Thanks, never would have found it buried in there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is called HTTP Authentication.
It takes place on the server, so you should use PHP in your case.

See examples at http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 0):

For others stumbling across this it seems the native browser prompt is intrinsically tied into authenticating a user for the entire time the browser is open or until they log out.

If you want a way to use the native browser prompt UI *while implementing your own authentication logic* (i.e. have the prompt appear multiple times in a single browsing session without logging a user out - like password action prompts) it seems this cannot be done.

I had to create a stylized jQuery prompt in my case (html would work too). It is consistent across browsers but obviously not native to any browser.